# Slicing out unique rows from a pandas DataFrame to store in separate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

SOLVED:

```py
# Split and save all unique parts to separate CSV
for unique_part in df['Part'].unique():
    df.loc[df['Part'] == unique_part].to_csv(f'Part_{unique_part}.csv')
```

I have a table containing production data on parts and the variables that were recorded during their production. I need to slice out all columns for unique part rows. I.E All columns for columns for part #1, #2, and #3 be slice and put into separate dataframes.

## FORMAT:

Part | Variable1 | Variable 2 etc

1-----------X---------------X

1-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

2-----------X---------------X

3-----------X---------------X

3-----------X---------------X

3-----------X---------------X

I have already tried 
Creating a dictionary to group by

```py
dict = {k: v for k, v in df.groupby('Part')}
```

*This didn't work because I couldn't properly convert from dict to DataFrame with the correct format*

I also tried creating a variable to store all unique part numbers, I just don't know how to loop through the main dataframe to slice out each unique part row section

```py
part_num = df['Part'].unique()
```

In summary, I need to create separate dataframes with all variable columns for each cluster of rows with unique part number ids.

Answer (score 2):

You can `groupby` and then `apply` to turn each group into a list of dicts, and then turn the groupby into a dict where each key is the unique `Part` value.

Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Part': [1,1,1,3,3,2,2,2],
    'other': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
})

d = df.groupby('Part').apply(lambda d: d.to_dict('records')).to_dict()
print d
```

will print

```
{1: [{'Part': 1, 'other': 'a'},
  {'Part': 1, 'other': 'b'},
  {'Part': 1, 'other': 'c'}],
 2: [{'Part': 2, 'other': 'f'},
  {'Part': 2, 'other': 'g'},
  {'Part': 2, 'other': 'h'}],
 3: [{'Part': 3, 'other': 'd'}, {'Part': 3, 'other': 'e'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you are on the right track with groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Part": [1, 1, 2, 2],
                    "Var1": [10, 11, 12, 13],
                    "Var2": [20, 21, 22, 23]})   
dfg = df.groupby("Part")

df1 = dfg.get_group(1)
df2 = dfg.get_group(2)
```

What do you want to DO with the data? Do you really need to create a bunch of individual data frames? The example below loops through each group (each part #) and prints. You could use the same method to do something or get something from each group without creating individual data frames.

```
for grp in dfg.groups:
    print(dfg.get_group(grp))
    print()
```

Output:

```
   Part  Var1  Var2
0     1    10    20
1     1    11    21

   Part  Var1  Var2
2     2    12    22
3     2    13    23
```

Comment: How do I call specific groups? Say I would like to call up for group for part 1? I don't understand how to do this :-(

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, there is an example in my answer. df1 is a data frame with all data for part 1. Use the get_group method with the part number as the input.

Comment: I have good news my friend. I was able to split everything up nicely with the following code